# How to fit a fixed effect to only one trait in bivariate mixed model in MCMCglmm?

Tags: r, correlation, mcmc

I tried to find a correlation between behavioural and physiological traits in animals. I used bivariate mixed model analysis in package MCMCglmm. Basal metabolic rate (BMR) and activity were my dependent variables. I set season, trial, sex and type of response to winter (RESP) as fixed effects. I also used ID as random effect.

The code goes like this:

```
prior<-list(R=list(V=diag(2),nu=1.02),
         G=list(G1=list(V=diag(2),nu=1.02)))

model1<-MCMCglmm(cbind(BMR,activity)~
        trait-1+trait:trial+trait:SEX+trait:RESP+trait:season,
        random=~us(trait):ID,
        rcov = ~us(trait):units,
        family=c("gaussian","gaussian"),
        prior=prior,data=data,nitt=NITT,thin=THIN,burnin=BURNIN,
        singular.ok=TRUE)
```

But since I know that BMR is strongly related with body mass I also wanted to add body mass to model. At the beginning I used residuals of BMR but somebody told me that I can fix body mass only to BMR and not to behavior. And here is my question: **How to fit a fixed effect to only one trait in bivariate model?**

I measured BMR only one per season, so I had NA's in 2 and 4 trials. I supposed that I should change NA's for 0 and I did it. But I got stuck here and I do not know how to move one.

Here is my data frame example.

```html
ID RESP SEX trial season BMR mb_BMR activity
4 R male  1 summer 0.184630641 21.8 0.76243
4 R male  2 summer NA NA 1.01422
4 R male  3 winter 0.222260753 29.1 0.43704
4 R male  4 winter NA NA -1.75655
5 NR male  1 summer 0.269151827 27.4 -0.27468
5 NR male  2 summer NA NA -0.19718
5 NR male  3 winter 0.22583699 31.9 0.94649
5 NR male  4 winter NA NA -0.7551
7 NR female 1 summer 0.252336196 26 0.7615
7 NR female 2 summer NA NA 1.15342
7 NR female 3 winter 0.19488432 23.3 0.30009
7 NR female 4 winter NA NA -0.94063
8 NR female 1 summer 0.216474311 23.8 -0.87454
8 NR female 2 summer NA NA -0.21937
8 NR female 3 winter 0.241733394 29.2 0.8145
8 NR female 4 winter NA NA -0.39096
9 NR male  1 summer 0.233164752 24.2 -0.12346
9 NR male  2 summer NA NA -1.26554
9 NR male  3 winter 0.258378951 30.8 0.35409
9 NR male  4 winter NA NA -1.31501
10 R male  1 summer 0.233973797 30.1 -0.23988
10 R male  2 summer NA NA -0.38281
10 R male  3 winter 0.283488877 35 1.03983
10 R male  4 winter NA NA -1.60583
11 NR male  1 summer 0.247344964 28 -1.2399
11 NR male  2 summer NA NA 0.0942
11 NR male  3 winter 0.294308448 34.1 0.87652
11 NR male  4 winter NA NA 0.34259
12 NR male  1 summer 0.25783053 29.8 0.16997
12 NR male  2 summer NA NA 0.40338
12 NR male  3 winter 0.24469161 29.3 1.87351
12 NR male  4 winter NA NA -0.03973
```

I would be grateful for any helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and think that using at.level() is the key. There are several examples in the MCMCglmm course notes. In your case, it should be something like at.level(trait,1):BodyMass

Comment: give some example too with detail.

Comment: model1<-MCMCglmm(cbind(BMR,activity)~
        trait-1+trait:trial+trait:SEX+trait:RESP+trait:season+at.level(trait,1):BodyMass,
        random=~us(trait):ID,
        rcov = ~us(trait):units,
        family=c("gaussian","gaussian"),
        prior=prior,data=data,nitt=NITT,thin=THIN,burnin=BURNIN,
        singular.ok=TRUE)